# Ошибка 503 после отправки ajaxForm + FormIt MODX

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, form, modx

Ребят, всем привет. Возникла проблема, не можем решить её уже более недели. Не отправляются формы с сайта, выдает ошибку POST legacy.vladislavchumak.com.ua/assets/components/ajaxform/action.php 503, убрал со страницу уже все что можно. Оставил только jQuery, подскажите в чем может быть проблема. [Ссылка на тестовую форму](https://legacy.vladislavchumak.com.ua/test-send)

Comment: Подскажите, есть ли что заслуживающее внимания в логах MODX и в серверных логах?

Comment: @AntonTarasov  #5 /home/acade131/public_html/core/components/pdotools/model/pdotools/pdoparser.class.php(65): modParser->processElementTags('', '<!DOCTYPE html>...', true, false, '[[', ']]', Array, 9)
#0 /home/acade131/public_html/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/30.include.cache.php(37): pdoFetch->run()
#1 /home/acade131/public_html/core/model/modx/modscript.class.php(76): include('/home/acade131/...')

Comment: @AntonTarasov [13-Mar-2021 22:25:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function parseProperties() on null in /home/acade131/public_html/core/model/modx/modelement.class.php on line 567

Comment: Простой вопрос, но иногда помогает - вы кеш MODX очищали? настройка базы данных, контекстов(если есть) и путей верная (все 4-ре config.inc.php)?